# Elixir phoenix project build on windows shows assets, Ubuntu does not

Tags: elixir, ubuntu-16.04, phoenix-framework, assets

I started an elixir phoenix project on my windows machine, and now, when trying to run it on ubuntu my assets no longer display. Is this a problem with Plug? All the assets were downloaded to my repository so are not missing, and they are in the same places as on my windows machine. I can't understand what's goin on.

[image]

Do you have to compile it differently on Ubuntu or something?

Why would it try to pull these assets through the router when I go to the home page?

```
iex(1)> [info] GET /
[debug] Processing with CryptWeb.PageController.index/2
  Parameters: %{}
  Pipelines: [:browser]
[info] Sent 200 in 268ms
[info] GET /css/freelancer.css
[debug] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /css/freelancer.css (CryptWeb.Router)
    (crypt) lib/crypt_web/router.ex:1: CryptWeb.Router.__match_route__/4
    (crypt) lib/phoenix/router.ex:303: CryptWeb.Router.call/2
    (crypt) lib/crypt_web/endpoint.ex:1: CryptWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
    (crypt) lib/plug/debugger.ex:99: CryptWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
    (crypt) lib/crypt_web/endpoint.ex:1: CryptWeb.Endpoint.call/2
    (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
    (cowboy) /home/jm/Crypt/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4
```

Comment: Do you see any warnings right after you run `mix phx.server`?

Comment: No, @JoséValim, it says just show the one [info] line that says "...with Cowboy using http://0.0.0.0:4000" now, by the way, 2 hours ago, right after I made this question I was invited to a closed beta system which turned out to be exactly what my project was, so maybe this issue isn't worth troubleshooting since I now may not finish this project. But if it's more of a ubiquitous problem in phx, idk. One thing I'll say is that when on windows I integrated this template into my project, perhaps if I integrated it wrong that caused the problem: startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I don't think it is an ubiquitous problem, it should work on Windows and any other OS. And when something goes wrong, we log it to the terminal. If you start a new app and it still persists, please provide a small application that reproduces the issue so we can take a further look at it.